# Installing cmake components into different directory

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have some component install rules for some executables:

```
install(TARGETS foo1 DESTINATION bin COMPONENT foo-utils)
install(TARGETS foo2 DESTINATION bin COMPONENT foo-utils)
install(TARGETS foo3 DESTINATION bin COMPONENT foo-utils)
```

Now, I have my own executable, and I want its install rule to also install all the `foo-utils` install rules - but instead of `bin`, I want them to go somewhere else.

```
add_executable(special ...)
# more options
add_dependencies(special foo1 foo2 foo3)
install(TARGETS special DESTINATION package/bin COMPONENT special)
add_custom_target(package-special
    DEPENDS special
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=special -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=foo-utils -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake"
     )
```

This works great, except building `package-special` produces:

```
$ tree install
install
├── bin
│   ├── foo1
│   ├── foo2
│   └── foo3
└── package
    └── bin
        └── special
```

How do I get it to produce:

```
$ tree install
install
└── package
    └── bin
        ├── foo1
        ├── foo2
        ├── foo3
        └── special
```

---

I will have multiple different `special`s that depend on the `foo-utils`, and I would like each `package-special` to install the `foo-utils` into a different directory. The `foo-utils` are also in a separate project from the `specials`, so I cannot `install(TARGETS ...)` the `foo-utils`.

Comment: Can you have a special variable, eg `FOO_UTILS_BIN_DEST` which defaults to `bin` for your standalone `foo-utils` package, but which you can set to a different value in your `package-special` custom target?

Comment: @SteveLorimer The utils are in a different project (added to question), and I have multiple packages that depend on them, so I'm not sure that would work?

Comment: Hmm, not sure I'm afraid. I see that `cmake_install.cmake` makes reference to a variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. Have you tried mucking with that when calling the install-component for foo-utils? Something like `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/package/bin"` or something along those lines?

Comment: @SteveLorimer YES! Brilliant. Can you write as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmake_install.cmake` uses a default install prefix if one doesn't already exist.

```
# Set the install prefix
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
endif()
```

As such, you can specify a value prior to calling the script for your `foo-utils` installation command.

```
add_custom_target(package-special
    DEPENDS special
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" 
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=special 
            -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" 
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=foo-utils 
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/package/bin" # <-- here
            -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake"
     )
```